# New C++ Project in Xcode 10.2 is not building

Tags: c++, xcode, build, compiler-errors, g++

Have a macOS Mojave 10.14.6 with Xcode 10.2 (10E125)

I simply created new c++ project in this way:

> Xcode -> New Project -> Command Line Tool -> [C++ Language] ->
>   Next/Done

And it's not building at all. I even not touched code.

**Here is errors**

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/string.h:74:64: Use of undeclared identifier 'strchr'

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/string.h:81:75: Use of undeclared identifier 'strpbrk'

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/string.h:88:65: Use of undeclared identifier 'strrchr'; did you mean 'strchr'?

etc...
```

[image]

**NOTE 1:** I tried to create same project but with C Language. And C Project working well until I'm adding `#include <vector>`. With vector I have same errors as in case with new C++ project.

**NOTE 2:** I don’t think, that something is not been installed on my system. Since the same code works well with Objective-C project.  (and I do not want to use h+mm  I want to use hpp+cpp, if that is the problem)

Comment: have you tried adding "libc++" as dependency? Project Settings -> Link Binaries -> + -> search for "libc++"

Comment: Yes I tried. But still the same errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have your same setup, and it doesn't occur to me. Was you XCode installation like this from the start, or did it happen after you've done a couple of projects?

If it happened later on, my reasoning is this; once I used the `fix` button inside of XCode, but, instead of fixing my own code, it went and modified a system header. Perhaps this is what happened to you as well?

If that's the case, you need to reinstall the whole party.

Comment: Well today, after a days of game with it, I decided to reinstall my imac from the beginning :). And now I can confirm that it works.